# Django Alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I want to show a JavaScript alert box when there is an error during login (wrong password or username), and reload the page. How can I do this from the Django template?

This is along the lines of what I had in mind:

```html
[% if messages %}
  <div class="javascript:alert">
    {{ somemessage }}
  </div>
 {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your alert call inside a script tag like this:

```
[% if messages %}
  <script>
    alert({{ somemessage }})
  </script>
 {% endif %}
```